# Composite foreign key relationship with primary key in relational database

Tags: database-design

I have these two tables:

```
Table1
(
  FileID,
  ...
)

Table2
(
  FileID,
  DataID,
  UsefulData
)
```

The `PK` for table `Table1` is `FileID`, and for `Table2` are `FileID` and `DataID`.

I think I can't create a FK between `Table1` and `Table2` only using the column `FileID` in both tables because `Table2` has a composite PK.

`Table2.DataID` is to identify the data stored in the column `Table2.UsefulData`.

Maybe, I can add another table between `Table1` and `Table2` to manage the FK: one column on `Table1` will refer to many rows in `Table2`.

Which is the better way to add a FK between `Table1` and `Table2`?

Comment: *I think I can't create a FK between Table1 and Table2 only using the column FileID in both tables because Table2 has a composite PK.* Why? https://dbfiddle.uk/n2GC-WFi FK needs in index existence, PK provides this. Datatypes are equal. So no another restrictions.

Comment: @Akinam thanks for your comment. I asked this because of this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3996774/foreign-key-relationship-with-composite-primary-keys-in-sql-server-2005/3996879#3996879 But, I probably misunderstood it. Thanks.